# What "lies" is Diana speaking of?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-1984

Diana and Barbara face off against each other:

> Barbara: You renounced your wish.
>
> Diana: I had to. And so do you. Nothing good is born from **lies**,
> Barbara.

What "lies" is Diana speaking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "lies" are the shortcut of the transformation bestowed by the wish. Diana is echoing words from Antiope after she took a shortcut to win the Themysciran games as a child.

> In the film's introductory Themyscira sequence, a young Diana receives a hard lesson in life and competition from her aunt and instructor, Antiope. After taking a shortcut to try and win the Themysciran games, Diana is stopped at the finish line by Antiope, and as a result loses the contest.
>
> Despite Diana's protests that she played the game fair and square through her own innovative measures, Antiope holds her ground and tells Diana the hard truth of the world: nothing can be gained rightfully through deception, and "No true hero is born from lies" - a theme that will resonate throughout the film.

[Source](https://screenrant.com/wonder-woman-1984-best-quotes/)